# How can I create a new column from a dataframe in pandas using a field as a dict key?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column with the values ​​from a dictionary using a dataframe field as a key.

```
dict = { "key"= { field="Value",...... },......}
df["field"] = dict[df["key"]]["field"]
```

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a new column from a dictionary? If so you can just add the dictionary to your dataframe in a new column.

df["new_column"] = dict